# Appending directory name to contents of tar.gz directory in the shell

Tags: shell, tar

I have a directory of compressed directories, like this:

```
MainDirectory/FolderA.tar.gz
MainDirectory/FolderB.tar.gz
```

Within each directory, some of the files have the same name. Ex.

```
MainDirectory/FolderA.tar.gz/file1.fasta
MainDirectory/FolderA.tar.gz/file2.fasta
MainDirectory/FolderB.tar.gz/file1.fasta
MainDirectory/FolderB.tar.gz/file1.fasta
```

I need to decompress each directory, rename each file with the name of the directory, and then recompress the individual files. My desired output is:

```
MainDirectory/FolderA_file1.fasta.bz2
MainDirectory/FolderA_file2.fasta.bz2
MainDirectory/FolderB_file1.fasta.bz2
MainDirectory/FolderB_file1.fasta.bz2
```

I came up with this code, but it renames the files to have a literal $f in:

```
cd MainDirectory/
for f in *.tar.gz
    do
    tar -xvzf $f --transform 's,^,${f},' 
    pbzip2 *.fastq 
    done
```

Output:

```
MainDirectory/'${f}file1.fastq.bz2'
MainDirectory/'${f}file2.fastq.bz2'
```

Please may you help me convert the command so it prepends the files with the actual folder name instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `tar` (your `--transform` is also a GNU extension anyway), you could do:

```
cd MainDirectory &&
  for f in *.tar.gz; do
    PREFIX=${f%.tar.gz} tar -xvvzf "$f" --to-command='
      pbzip2 > "${PREFIX}_$TAR_FILENAME.bz2"'
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing the extraction and recompression in two steps:

```
cd MainDirectory && for f in *.tar.gz; do
  tar --transform="s,^,${f%.tar.gz}_," --show-transformed-names -xvzf "$f"
done && pbzip2 *.fasta
```

Option `--show-transformed-names` and `-v` are only used to display the transformed filenames.